# FOSOAuthServerBundle + FOSRestBundle + CamelCase = Not authenticating

Tags: rest, fosrestbundle, symfony-2.8, camelcasing, fosoauthserverbundle

I have been working on my server in Symfony 2.8, building a rest api which returns json objects in camelCase style, the problem now is that when I integrate the OauthServer bundle it lauches this error `Invalid grant_type parameter or parameter missing"`, I understand that this happens because I am using the `array_normalizer: fos_rest.normalizer.camel_keys`  body listener in my `fos_rest` configuration. Here my code in `configuration.yml`:

```
fos_rest:
    #other listeners#
    body_listener:
        array_normalizer: fos_rest.normalizer.camel_keys
    zone: 
         - { path: ^/api }
```

And here my Oauth configuration in the `security.yml`:

```
firewalls:
    oauth_token:
        pattern: ^/oauth/v2/token
        security: false
    api:
        pattern: ^/api                             
        fos_oauth: true                            
        stateless: true                            
        anonymous: false
```

I found out I was not the first person who this ever happened, and that the `zone` attribute was added to mitigate this, but in my case it does work only with everything under the `^/api` because when I change the pattern it stops using the listeners as expected but when I call the `^/oauth/v2/token` path it seems to ignore the `zone` given path.

To retrieve my token, I am using the next POST request:

```
{
    grant_type= "password" 
    client_id= "clientId"
    client_secret= "clientSecret"
    username= "user"
    password= "password"
}
```

I want to clarify that if I deactivate the listener I obtain the token successfully, but the rest of my app stops working because it uses camelCase everywhere, I know that once alternative would be to serialize my data in the client side, but it is quite complicated at the moment.

What am I doing wrong? I can't figure out what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as workaround you can use instead of `POST`, `GET` like this

```
http://example.com/oauth/v2/token?client_id=[CLIENT_ID]&client_secret=[SECRET]&grant_type=password&username=[USERNAME]&password=[PASSWORD]
```

Then you don`t have to worry about body serializers.